# Mdb datatable does not rendering data in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, datatable, datatables, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a datatable with mdbootstrap in vue.js. 
I would like to update table data on events and when initialized but it does not work.

Template;

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <mdb-datatable
                :data="data"
                striped
                bordered
        />

    </div>
```

Script;

```
    import { mdbDatatable } from 'mdbvue';
export default {

    name: 'userManagement',
    components: {
        mdbDatatable
    },
    data() {
        return {
            className:"",
            classList: [],

            data: {
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: 'Name',
                        field: 'className',
                        sort: 'asc'
                    }, {
                        label: 'ID',
                        field: 'id',
                        sort: 'asc'
                    }
                ],
                rows: [
                    {
                        className: 'Tiger Nixon',
                        id:1
                    },
                    {
                        className: 'Garrett Winters',
                        id:2
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {

        getClassList(){
            var _this = this;
            this.$axios.get('my_url/admin/classes').then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {

                    _this.data.rows = [];
                    response.data.forEach(function (obj) {
                        let item = {
                            className: obj.className,
                            id: obj.id
                        };
                        _this.data.rows.push(item);
                    });
                }
            }).catch(function (err) {
                alert("" + err);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getClassList();
    },
```

It always shows default values, I check the data rows from console the value seems to be updated but no change on the datatable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We've found the solution for Your issue.
The new code is available here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/tables/datatables/#external-api

Also to make sure the data is reactive it's necessary to add the following code to the Datatable component in our package:

```
watch: {
    data(newVal) {
      this.columns = newVal.columns;
    },
    (...)
}
```

It will be fixed in the next MDB Vue release.

Answer (score 0):

I installed mdbvue 5.5.0 which includes the change that mikolaj described. This caused the table columns to update when changed but in order to get the rows to update too I had to add to the watch method in Datatable.vue as follows:

```
watch: {
data(newVal) {
  this.columns = newVal.columns;
  this.rows = newVal.rows;
},
```